# How to JOIN tables to get all of Table A, and most of Table B

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty sure I need a LEFT JOIN for this, but I have a snag.  I need to pull one column from table B dependant on a column in table A.

```
TABLE A = list
list_id
user_id
operator_id
operator_name
operator_level


TABLE B = operators
operators_id
type
image
skill1
skill2
skill3
1
2
3
...
10
```

Here is the SQL Query that I have now:

```
SELECT * FROM list l 
    LEFT JOIN operators o ON l.operator_id = o.operators_id 
WHERE l.user_id=1 
ORDER BY o.10 DESC
```

It returns all of Table A, which I want, and also returns all of Table B, which I don't need.
The columns 1-10 contain INT values, and those columns correspond to the operator_level in Table A.

So really what I need is to create a temp column, and put whatever INT is in the 1-10 column that corresponds to the operator_level, or only return that column for that row.  I have no idea how to do that though.

Here is some sample data, and expected results:

```
list list_id, user_id, operator_id, operator_name, operator_level
    1,       1,         2,     Johnson, Bob,        1
    2,       1,         3,     Mouse, Mickey,       9
    3,       1,         2,     Duck, Donald,        5

operators operator_id, type,    image,     skill1,    skill2, skill3,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10
     1,      pilot,   image.jpg, F16,       B32,                   , 50,  60,  70,  80,  90,  100, 110, 120, 130, 140
     2,      medic,   image.jpg, first aid, trauma, general surgery, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145
     3,      kitchen, image.jpg, knife,     soup,                  , 20,  22,  24,  26,  28,  30,  32,  34,  36,  38

Expected Results list_id, user_id, operator_id, operator_name, operator_level, type,    image,     skill1,    skill2, skill3,         op_rate
    1,       1,         2,     Johnson, Bob,        1,        pilot,   image.jpg, F16,       B32,                     50
    2,       1,         3,     Mouse, Mickey,       9,        medic,   image.jpg, first aid, trauma, general surgery, 140
    3,       1,         2,     Duck, Donald,        5,        kitchen, image.jpg, knife,     soup,                    28
```

Sorry, it lined up well in my editor, but lost the alignment. when I pasted.

Added sample data to sqlfiddle, don't know how to add expected results there.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/390d8/1

Comment: yes you have one to many relation and hence its selecting multiple data. Could you provide some sample data and the expected resultset in http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Added sample data and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basics right withe the outer join, but what you can do is limit the fields you select in your query like this:

```
select
    l.list_id,
    l.user_id,
    l.operator_id,
    l.operator_name,
    l.operator_level,
    `1`+`2`+`3`+...+`10` as opLevel
FROM 
    list l 
        LEFT JOIN operators o 
            ON l.operator_id = o.operators_id 
WHERE 
    l.user_id=1 
ORDER BY 
    o.10 DESC
```

This is based on the fact that it would seem you have 0 for and or a value for the right operator.

Having said that, why on earth would you have ten fields to store one bit of information? Your table should only have the ONE field called something like "OperatorLevel" and have the value in it - unless I am missing something.

Alternately, you could also use a greatest() function in your query if you have multiple values and you want the highest one:

```
select
    l.list_id,
    l.user_id,
    l.operator_id,
    l.operator_name,
    l.operator_level,
    greatest(`1`, `2`, ... `10`) as opLevel
FROM 
    list l 
        LEFT JOIN operators o 
            ON l.operator_id = o.operators_id 
WHERE 
    l.user_id=1 
ORDER BY 
    o.10 DESC
```

Edit: Okay, based on additional information you can use the following (ick ick ick) statement:

```
select
    l.list_id,
    l.user_id,
    l.operator_id,
    l.operator_name,
    l.operator_level,
    case
        when l.operator_level=1 then o.`1`
        when l.operator_level=2 then o.`2`
        when l.operator_level=3 then o.`3`
        // etc etc yuck!
        when l.operator_level=10 then o.`10`
    end as yicky
FROM 
    list l 
        LEFT JOIN operators o 
            ON l.operator_id = o.operators_id 
WHERE 
    l.user_id=1 
ORDER BY 
    o.10 DESC
```

Edit 2:

I would very much suggest a data normalisation.

Given what you have as data, it seems that you are duplicating data to all sorts of users. This kinda sounds like a nightmare to update. From what I understand, it seems that there is a pay scale for each "skill" and it goes up based on the level of the operator?

I would make a table with the following structure (assumptions based on user 1):

```
skill   level   value
 B32     1   25
 B32     2   30
.....
 B32     10  75
 F16     1   25
 F16     2   30
...
 F16     10  75
```

Then you could simply perform a link from the "list" table to the "operators" table, and then link to the "grades" table based on data within then.

This would make for a much simpler query.

Having said ALL THAT, I would actually look at normalizing your "operators" table down to skills only. Move the "type" and "image" into the "list" table (and call it users while you are at it).

Now the "operators" table should be renamed to a skillset table with data like this:

```
userID  skill   Level
 1   F16     4
 1   B32     8
 2   F_Aid   2
```

This would allow you to have users with more than 3 skills as well as allowing you to easily record each skill level of the user. They might be a superhero at B32, but only mediocre at F16.

Comment: Operators get paid diff rates depending on their type and their level.  So for instance type-pilot, has 50, 55, 62,...150. in the 1-10 fields.  So if they are level 5, I only need the value in the '5' field.

Comment: @Dizzy49 See edit. And yickity yick on the table structure :( Can you change it? Say you can. Please change it :)

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it.  I have hundreds of operators with their own pay scales.  I've only entered 10 to work with until I get everything sorted.

Comment: The operators table has unique types, but may have overlapping skills.  Pay is based on the type, not skill.  The list table is unique individuals which will have duplicate operators.  I see where you are going with it and I'm going to make some changes.  I'm going to pull the rates and skills out and put them in their own tables.  I'll work on it more later and post an update :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one int column has value maybe something like this?

SELECT l.*, COALESCE(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) opLevel
FROM list l 
LEFT JOIN operators o ON l.operator_id = o.operators_id 
WHERE l.user_id=1 
ORDER BY COALESCE(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) DESC